# IIS7 showing iisstart.html instead of default document

Tags: iis-7, web-config

I've a Sitefinity 4.1 website running on IIS7, I am setting "Default.aspx" at the top of the default documents list, but when I access http://www.*****.org/ it shows the IIS7 welcome page.

When I access http://www.*******.org/default.aspx it works just fine.

I checked the defaultDocument section in the Web.config and it is set correctly, recycled the app pool, restarted the website site, nothing so far.

What am I missing?

**EDIT :**

It seems to be a caching problem, if I add junk query string parameters it redirects to the correct page, ex : http://www.*****.org/?aaa

Comment: I realize that this question is several months old, and that your website is functioning properly now.  What did you do to fix this?  Did you manually have to specify default.aspx as the startup page in the Project Properties?

Comment: It was just a caching problem actually

Answer (score 10):

Hit F5 on the browser.  iisstart.html often is cached in the browser.

Comment: or you could try Ctrl+F5

Comment: The Software Developer's equivalent of "Can you please try turning it off and on again..." Worked for me! :) Thanks

Comment: For those that don't know: CTRL+F5 will bypass the cache when reloading the page only in windows systems.

Windows: ctrl + F5
Mac/Apple: Apple + R or command + R
Linux: F5

Comment: Oh man I was about to go down a rabbit hole.. glad I stumbled upon this..

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + shift delete on your browser clear all the cache.
then close browser and try again