# When navigating to the site root, I get an IIS splash screen

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have a website configured in IIS 7, with an application (another site) located that site.

My bindings are set so that if I navigate to mysite.com it should open the root site, and mysite.com/training it opens up my training site.  The mysite.com/training URL works fine, but the root does not, it just shows the IIS splash screen.

If I navigate to a specific page on the root like mysite.com/index.aspx it works fine, it just won't open the default page (which is set correctly) when navigating to the root.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here are my binding settings:

Type: http. 
IP Address: All Unassigned.
Port: 80. 
Host name: mysite.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. make sure in IIS 'index.aspx' is listed in the default documents list.
2. maybe its a cache issue, check out this post: [IIS7 showing iisstart.html instead of default document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863283/iis7-showing-iisstart-html-instead-of-default-document)

Comment: ok. this happened to me once and that is how i fixed it. if i think of anything else i will come back and post.

Comment: i saw this and maybe its a cache issue, try it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863283/iis7-showing-iisstart-html-instead-of-default-document