# IIS7 screen when i try to access through an IP

Tags: iis, iis-7

I'm trying to view a site who require user and pass. I have naturally username, password and the IP of the site. Unfortunately the site give me IIS7 screen. I've already try backdoor access but nothing. I have to set the IIS even if the site is not on my device but on the net? My OS is Windows 8 x64.

Thanks for your help, and sorry for the bad english ;)

Comment: There is a similar post like you. This might [help][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966439/when-navigating-to-the-site-root-i-get-an-iis-splash-screen

Comment: Do you mean the caching problem? I didn't solve. Even add 'index.aspx' didn't help me.