# Caching issue causes site goes to IIS splash page

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis

My company creates sub-domains for our customers that sign up with us. For the longest time now, we'd create the site (for example https://foo.domainname.com), and it would go directly to the application. However recently, after creating a site when you go to navigate to it, it just shows the IIS 7 Splash page. After doing a bit of Googling, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966439/when-navigating-to-the-site-root-i-get-an-iis-splash-screen), and it appears to be the case, because when you go to the main page directly, instead of the root, it works. Then after that the root works as expected.

It's great we have a way to help our customers now, however telling our customers to clear their cache and/or navigate to the main page directly is not ideal for many obvious reasons. So considering this is a new behavior, it seems safe to assume something is not working quite right. How do I go about fixing this, because I am stumped.

Comment: Delete `iisstart.html` from the Default Web Site, and that prevents the cache from being there initially.

Answer (score 0):

iis is also set to "application pool" of the sites.
Create and set new "application pool" sites. Thus, they work more efficiently.

https://docs.kentico.com/k11/installation/deploying-kentico-to-a-live-server/creating-virtual-directories-and-application-pools-in-iis-7-5-and-7-0